# Move semantics, why isnt the move constructor called?

Tags: c++, move-semantics

here's what I've got:

```
class A {
    class B{
        A* owner;
        B(A* owner){
            this->owner = owner;
        }
        B(B&& second)
            : owner(std::move(second.owner));
        {}

        B& operator=(B&& second){
            this->owner = second.owner;
        }
    };

    B* object;
    int a;
    string b;

    A(int a, string b){
        this->a = a;
        this->b = b;
        object = nullptr;
    }

    void create_B(){
        if(object == nullptr)
            object = new B(this);
    }

    A& operator=(A&& second){
        this->a = second.a;
        this->b = second.b;
        this->object = std::move(second.object);
        second.object = nullptr;
        return *this;
    }

    A(A&& second)
        : a(second.a)
        , b(second.b)
        , object(std::move(second.object)){
        second.object = nullptr;
    }
};
```

Now what bothers me is that when I do something like this:

```
A a1(2, "aaa"), a2(3, "bbb");
a1.create_B();
swap(a1, a2);
```

everything changes it place correctly (A's move and move assignment constructors are called properly) but the B's owner does not change (while I would want it to change to a2 since we swapped).

Why isnt the B's move constructor/ move assignment constructor called here?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Because the field `object` is moved (copied) as a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

B's move constructor is not being called because you are moving a B* (pointer to B), not a B.  Try defining object to be an instance of B.